# How to destructure from an object and keep the same object?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add an event listener to a field, such as this

```
field.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // do something
  }
});
```

Is there a clean way to keep `event` and to destructure `keyCode` from it, because I need both?

Answer (score 2):

You can destructure the object in a new const variable.

```
field.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  const { keyCode } = event;
  if (keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: should probably be `keyCode` (capital `c`)

Answer (score 2):

You could destructure to object, in the parameter list, the object is no gone, but you could pull it from the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Which does not make the code nicer ...

```js
function perform({ baz }) {
    console.log(baz);
    console.log(arguments[0]);
}

var object = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 };

perform(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately, no, not the way I think you mean. You could do something like this:

```
field.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  // whatever you want to destructure
  const {keyCode} = event; 
  if (keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // do something
  }
});
```

This probably isn't that helpful, though, as I'm sure you want to destructure in the parameter list of your event handler.

Comment: this won't work as the execution context of `preventDefault()` needs to be an event

Comment: Oh, good point. I should wait until the coffee kicks in before I answer these questions. :-)